# Is $u''$ always synonymous to $\Delta u$?

Tags: laplacian

Is $u''$ always synonymous to $\Delta u$?

Or if not, then what does $u''$ refer to?

This is in contexts of giving PDE problems e.g. as:

$$\Delta u = 0$$

Sometimes I see

$$u'' = 0$$

Can I assume in this case that $$\Delta u = u''$$

Comment: If $u$ is a function of time and space then $u''$ can mean derivative wrt time and $\Delta u$ is Laplacian.

Comment: In a context where derivatives make no sense, dashes as in $u''$ might be used to decorate variables. You should provide some context for us to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1D they're the same, in higher dimensions $u''$ is ambiguous.

Comment: Can you explain? My PDE notes seem to use them as synonyms regardless of dimension.

Comment: @mavavilj Maybe give an example; it would be very strange to use $u''$ as $\Delta u$ in, say, 2D. In part because the Laplacian doesn't really split into two identical operations (it's grad then div).

Comment: Nevermind I made some error in reading, it seems that the case I was reading was actually for $u$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$. So it's used for a 1D case.

Comment: I have never seen $\Delta u$ in 1D case. Looks weird.